# Finding $P(X_1+X_2+X_3<1)$ given $X=(X_1,X_2,X_3)$ is random vector

Tags: probability

> Given $X = (X_1,X_2,X_3)$ be a continuous random vector with $ 0 <X_i<1 $
>   and the density function is
>   $$f_X(x_1,x_2,x_3) =\frac23(x_1+x_2+x_3).$$
>   Find $P(x_1+x_2+x_3<1)$.

How to find the density of $X_1+X_2+X_3$? Can anyone please visualize this or explain how to think $x_1+x_2+x_3<1$ as a constraint to a triple integration? I am not sure how to integrate a vector.

Answer (score 0):

You have to compute $\int_0^{1} \int_0^{1} \int_0^{1} \frac 2 3 (x_1+x_2+x_3) I_{\{(x_1,x_2,x_3):x_1+x_2+x_3 <1\}}\, dx_1\, dx_2\, dx_3 $. You can do this by the change of variables $u_1=x_1+x_2+x_3, u_2=x_2,u_3=x_3$. The Jacobian of this transformation is $1$. I leave rest to you.